# Using NHibernate.Linq and getting 2 queries for a simple select, why?

Tags: linq, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

so here's the code with irrelevant bits left out:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetByQuery(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter
{
    try 
    {
        return Session.Linq<T>().Where(filter);
     }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // custom exception handling here
    }
    finally
    {
        CloseSession();
    }
    return null;
}
```

and an example of it being called looks like this:

```
IEnumerabl<ClientReport> clientReports = 
clientReportRepository.GetByQuery(item => item.ClientId = id);
```

So as you can see, nothing fancy and being called in this way, we're hitting one table in the database with no relationships to any other tables. But when I have show_sql = true in the configuration, It's displaying 2 of the same query.
Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Can you confirm two queries are actually being executed by using NHProf?

Comment: I had the dba's monitor the database and two queries were execute. It seems that one runs when I call the GetByQuery method and then again when I go to enumerate the query as Diego mentions below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`clientReports` will probably execute the query every time you enumerate it (or get the `Count()`, for example).

To avoid that, use `.ToList()` in the assignment.